# How to create a custom tab that redirects to a specific URL

Tags: administration, tab, url

I would like to create a tab in Salesforce called 'Activities', and when clicked, it redirects to https://na1.salesforce.com/007, the Activity List Page in Salesforce.

The web tab is not an option, and I know there are some AppExchange Apps that mimic the Activities List Page. I'm however curious to know if I can link to this or any other URL for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Visualforce tab that references this page:

```
<apex:page controller="ActivitiesController" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

that in turn uses this controller:

```
public with sharing class ActivitiesController {
    public PageReference redirect() {
        return new PageReference('/007');
    }
}
```

It does open the Activity list page, but it is presented with the Home tab selected not the initiating tab selected.